# How I can save the data of a TextField to a file using JFileChooser?

Tags: netbeans, save, textfield, jfilechooser

I have been trying to save the data of a TextField using JFileChooser in Java on Netbeans.
That's what I have done until now:

```
private void Cmd_saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                      
    int p = jOptionPane3.showConfirmDialog(null, 
       "Do you want to save this","Save",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION );

    if (p == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();  
        chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example, you can do it differently:

```
//imports

public class FileChooser extends JFrame
{
    private JFileChooser fileChooser = null;
    private JTextField name_textField = null;
    private JLabel name_label = null;
    private JButton save_text = null;

    public FileChooser()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        name_label = new JLabel("Enter your name");
        name_textField = new JTextField(15);
        save_text = new JButton("Save your name to a file!");
        save_text.addActionListener(new Name_ActionListener());

        add(name_label);
        add(name_textField);
        add(save_text);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private class Name_ActionListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                    "Do you really want to save the your name?", 
                    "Save", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if(answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

                // This is a reference which allows you to save a FileOutputStream object
                OutputStream out = null;

                // File is a class which represents the physical file
                // Creating a file with which represents the physical file
                // with the absolute path chosen by the user using fileChooser
                File file = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

                try
                {
                    //You can use other classes to store data on the file like Formatter
                    out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    for(byte b : name_textField.getText().getBytes())
                        out.write(b);
                }
                catch(IOException e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if(out != null)
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            out.close();
                            out = null;
                        }
                        catch(IOException e2)
                        {
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }       
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    }
}
```

Have a look also to the documentation about FileOutputStream and similar classes to understand better how to manage files in Java.